# RecyclerView not populating from android database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-room

Im trying to implement Room Database to populate my recyclerView, and it seemed to work, albeit briefly, however now it no longer seems to populate & I cannot find the cause, I ran a log check on my getItemCount() method and its returning the size as zero.

**Adapter class**

```
public class routeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<routeAdapter.RouteHolder> {


    public List<Route> userRoutes = new ArrayList<>();

    class RouteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView routeName;
        private TextView routeDesc;

        public RouteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            routeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routelistnamer);
            routeDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.routelistdesc);

        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RouteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.routeadapterrow,parent,false);
        return new RouteHolder(itemview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RouteHolder holder, int position) {
        Route currentRoute = userRoutes.get(position);
        holder.routeName.setText(currentRoute.getRouteName());
        holder.routeDesc.setText(currentRoute.getRouteDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("Pointyyy", "getItemCount: "+userRoutes.size());
        return userRoutes.size();

    }


    public void setRoutes(List<Route> routes) {
            this.userRoutes = routes;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

    }




}
```

**ViewModel class**

```
public class RouteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private RouteRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Route>> allRoutes;

    public RouteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new RouteRepository(application);
        allRoutes = repository.getAllRoutes();
    }

    //wraper methods
    public void insert(Route route) {
        repository.insert(route);
    }

    public void update(Route route) {
        repository.update(route);
    }

    public void delete(Route route) {
        repository.delete(route);
    }

    public void deleteAllRoutes() {
        repository.deleteAllRoutes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Route>> getAllRoutes() {
        return allRoutes;
    }
}
```

**Database class**

```
public abstract class RouteDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

    //create instance of database.
    private static RouteDataBase instance;

    public abstract  RouteDao routeDao();

    public static synchronized RouteDataBase getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), RouteDataBase.class, "route_database")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(roomCallBack)
                    .build();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallBack = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {


        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            new populateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
        }
    };

    private static class populateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private RouteDao routeDao;


        private populateDbAsyncTask(RouteDataBase db) {
            routeDao = db.routeDao();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            point m1 = new point(54.20494, -5.89619, "Start Point - Donard Car Park", PointType.START_POINT);
            point m2 = new point(54.20463, -5.89666, "", PointType.STANDARD_POINT);
            point m3 = new point(54.20463, -5.89708, "", PointType.STANDARD_POINT);
            point m4 = new point(54.20463, -5.89708, "", PointType.ENDPOINT);

            List<point> donardPoints = new ArrayList<point>();
            donardPoints.add(m1);
            donardPoints.add(m2);
            donardPoints.add(m3);
            donardPoints.add(m4);

            routeDao.insert(new Route("Slemish", "Based in Ireland", donardPoints));
            routeDao.insert(new Route("K2", "Second Highest", (List<point>) donardPoints));
            routeDao.insert(new Route("Cavehill", "Outskirts", (List<point>) donardPoints));

            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

**Route Item XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adapterRelLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/routelistnamer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12sp"
        android:padding="12sp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/routelistdesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12sp"
        android:padding="12sp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Recyclerview XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".routeLister">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/routeRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/routeadapterrow" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: You need to work your way up from the view to see why there is no data. 
Is `setRoutes` called and is the list size also 0?
Then does `repository.getAllRoutes();` return a size of 0?.
Finally does the data base actually have the items in. Android studio has a DB inspector located at the bottom under app inspector.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @badvok, Just checked and indeed the DB tables are empty,(also didn't know about this inspector, very handy!) So I wonder is my doInBackground method the cause?
The log shows data in getAllRoutes 'androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData@6c8ed84'

Comment: I cant see your Route (entity) but its most likely that the insert fails since room cannot accept List<> as a field. If you don't add the `donardPoints ` I suspect it might work. 

Then then gives you the new problem of getting the `donardPoints `  into your DB. If the relationship is 1 to 1. Personally id modify my Route object to take in the fields that each `point` has. 

If its 1 to many, or many to many. You will need to give the points their own db table, and a unique id that links up to the Route they belong too.